# The definition of “Hoist a flag”

Tags: idioms

Although I know that in the phrase of “hoist a flag” the word “flag” must be tangible, I just wanted to know that if I use this idiom as a figurative way to express my feeling, can make sense or not:
For example:
“She was tolerating the pressure to hoist the flag of courageousness.”
Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To 'fly' or 'raise' a flag are commonly used in a figurative sense. 'Flying the flag' for something or someone figuratively means to demonstrate support. 'Hoist' basically means the same as 'raise' in the context of a flag, so I see no problem with it. It would certainly be understood and may well have already been used. In fact, 'hoist' carries a much richer meaning than 'raise', as it conveys the effort involved.